# How to calculate the date that is X number of week days from a given date?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am able to add 102 days to any date I input, but now the problem is, it should be 102 *week* days (excluding weekends).  How can I do that?

Here's my code for just adding 102 days:

```
private void txtStartKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    try {    
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(txtStart.getText());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");     
        Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 102);
        String expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        txtExpiry.setText(expDateString);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not getting your question. You want to include the weekends or not?

Comment: excluding the weekends. it should be 102 days expiration but the weekends should not be counted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should add `weekdays` week days (weekends are ignored) onto a date. If you pass `0` for `weekdays` it will get the next working day. So, `Saturday + 1 weekday = Tuesday`.

```
private static Date addWeekdaysToDate(Date date, int weekdays) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int originalDayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int numWeeks = weekdays / 5;
    int remainderDays = weekdays % 5;
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numWeeks * 7 + remainderDays);

    int adjustmentDays = 0;
    if (originalDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        adjustmentDays = 1;
    } else if (originalDayOfWeek + remainderDays > Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        adjustmentDays = 2;
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, adjustmentDays);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your code, just replace with the following:

```
private static Date addWeekdaysToDate(Date date, int weekdays) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int originalDayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int numWeeks = weekdays / 5;
    int remainderDays = weekdays % 5;
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numWeeks * 7 + remainderDays);

    int adjustmentDays = 0;
    if (originalDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        adjustmentDays = 1;
    } else if (originalDayOfWeek + remainderDays > Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        adjustmentDays = 2;
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, adjustmentDays);
    return cal.getTime();
}

private static SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private void txtStartKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    try {
        txtExpiry.setText(
            inputDateFormat.format(
                addWeekdaysToDate(inputDateFormat.parse(txtStart.getText()), 102)
            )
        );
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 102; i++)
{
    DateTime thisOne = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-13");

    string thisDay = thisOne.ToString("dddd");

    if (thisDay != "Saturday" && thisDay != "Sunday")
    {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated for custom date

Comment: @JMK, your solution is in C#.  The question is about Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am just pasting the code piece which excludes the weekend alone. Please use this according to your purpose

```
int numberOfDays = 102;
int count = 1;
String expDateString = null;
Date temp = date1;
while(count != numberOfDays){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");     
    Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(temp);
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
    if(!(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY)){
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, count);
        count++;
    }
    temp = cal.getTime();
    expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by this --> Date temp = date1;

Comment: this is your original startDate which you have assigned from txtStart right. I dont want to change that instance so i have assigned that to a temporary variable.

Comment: .I have done your code but when i run it, the UI sort of hung up when i try to enter a last digit of the date on txtStart.

Comment: please check your console for any exceptions. When i ran this program as a standalone application, i mean with public static void main it works fine. please check for the exceptions if any.

Comment: i got it..instead of keyReleased event try writing the code in focusOut event, because the keyRelease will get triggered for each key release and you dont require that because you will get the full date once you focus out..otherwise it will have exceptions in the date formatting...

Comment: in that case you need to catch the exception and suppress that..so that your UI doesnt not hang up...

Comment: i can see only FocusGained and FocusLost event.

Comment: FocusOut is nothing but FocusLost

Comment: i get this error: using focuslost. run:
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.text.resources.FormatData, locale en_US

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8840/discussion-between-raddykrish-and-zairahcs)

Comment: I am not sure about this exception. Are you using any resource bundles in your applications and because of that its causing that exception. Ideally focusLost event should not give such errors.

Comment: i am not familiar with resource bundles but i don't think I have resource bundles on my application.

Comment: may be when you are doing a focus lost you need to check for the text as not null in the txtStart, since if its empty and you are running the above code it might give some parsing exceptions. please debug and see where exactly you are getting that exception. that would resolve the issues.